# HOW TO GET SEQUENTIAL DATE RANGE IN BIQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data like the following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjVRk.png)

I want to get a table like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8exI.png)

how can i get the active date as drawn...? Please help

Comment: Please try to show tables/code in formatted text that we can copy/paste instead of as images, please see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array) function in BigQuery. More specifically:

```
WITH customers AS (
SELECT 123456 as customer_id,
DATE("2022-01-01") as start_date,
DATE("2022-01-03") as last_active
)

SELECT customer_id, start_date, last_active, active_ 
FROM customers, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, last_active, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as active_
```